# Push the branch into the trunk with SVN

Tags: svn, merge

I want to "overwrite"  trunk with branchX.

```
trunk is say at version 10.
branchX is say at version 40.
```

I want all files in branchX to "become" trunk. From my understanding I want to merge and choose *(mc) mine-conflict* somehow. One note, I want to keep comments from both branches, if possible.

```
e.g.
trunk commit 9- refactored out file Z
branchX commit 38 - new files for new feature YYY
```

I am using Eclipse, but from my reading, easier from command-line.

Cmdline steps:

1. svn checkout branchX
2. ?
3. ?
   ...

Comment: What do you mean with having trunk and branches in different revisions? Revision is a concept that applies to repository as a whole. Perhpas you want to merge branch contents as they were in an earlier revision rather than HEAD?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález If there were a file change in trunk, say file G. Replace it with file G from branchX. Every conflict, every file.

Answer (score 0):

You want to merge your branch into the trunk with automatic conflict resolution:

```
svn checkout [repository-path]/trunk
cd trunk
svn merge [repository-path]/branchX --accept theirs-full
svn commit -m "Reintegrate branchX"
svn up
```

In your copy of the trunk, by default, you will not see the commit messages you wrote when committing in branchX:

```
svn log -l1
```

However, you can see them with the `-g` (or `--use-merge-history`) option:

```
svn log -l1 -g
```

I do not know how you can pass this option in Eclipse.